# It's an array but it says invalid arguments on foreach

Tags: php, arrays

I got a problem here, why my array cannot go through foreach ? This is my code, I wonder why it says invalid argument. Please help me, thank you.

**source**

```
    /*some of block code here*/

    $content = array();
    $content['table_1'] = array();
    $columns = array('B', 'E', 'H', 'K');
    $rows = array(
        0 => 7,
        1 => 8,
        2 => 9,
        3 => 10,
    );
    foreach ($columns AS $column) {
        foreach ($rows AS $row_key => $row_value) {
            $content['table_1'][$column . $row_value] = $data['jenis_kelamin']['l']['count'][$row_key];
        }
    }

    $columns = array('C', 'F', 'I', 'L');
    foreach ($columns AS $column) {
        foreach ($rows AS $row_key => $row_value) {
            $content['table_1'][$column . $row_value] = $data['jenis_kelamin']['p']['count'][$row_key];
        }
    }
    return $content;
```

**print file**

```
$tableContent = $this->cetak->Statistik_Content()['table_1'];

   if (is_array($tableContent) || $tableContent instanceof Traversable) {
        foreach ($tableContent AS $list) {
            foreach ($list AS $key => $value) { // **This one generates an error**
                $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($key, $value);
            }
        }
    }
```

If I check it with is array, the condition true, but when I try to put it in foreach, it says invalid, I have no idea, I already look into this problem for hours and still can't fix it.

**Var Dump $tableContent**

```
array(32) { ["B7"]=> int(0) ["B8"]=> int(0) ["B9"]=> int(1) ["B10"]=> int(1) ["E7"]=> int(0) ["E8"]=> int(0) ["E9"]=> int(1) ["E10"]=> int(1) ["H7"]=> int(0) ["H8"]=> int(0) ["H9"]=> int(1) ["H10"]=> int(1) ["K7"]=> int(0) ["K8"]=> int(0) ["K9"]=> int(1) ["K10"]=> int(1) ["C7"]=> int(0) ["C8"]=> int(0) ["C9"]=> int(1) ["C10"]=> int(0) ["F7"]=> int(0) ["F8"]=> int(0) ["F9"]=> int(1) ["F10"]=> int(0) ["I7"]=> int(0) ["I8"]=> int(0) ["I9"]=> int(1) ["I10"]=> int(0) ["L7"]=> int(0) ["L8"]=> int(0) ["L9"]=> int(1) ["L10"]=> int(0) }
```

Comment: So we need to guess which `foreach` generates warning, right?

Comment: Yeah, it says something like this *Invalid argument supplied for foreach()** @u_mulder

Comment: For __which one__ of __six__ `foreach`es I see here?

Comment: ah sorry, the print file one. I will edit my question @u_mulder

Comment: I assume that $this->cetak->Statistik_Content()['table_1'] is the problematic section.

Comment: var_dump($tableContent) and check what are you getting..

Comment: @4EACH I already move the ['table_1'] to foreach ($tableContent['table_1'] AS $list) and it still error

Comment: @TouheedKhan I already put the var dump on the question.

Comment: As @TouheedKhan wrote, var_dump($tableContent) and see what you get.

Comment: @4EACH I already edit the question and provide it with the var dump. Please check it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need of another `foreach` if `$tableContent` is a single dimensional array.

**Try this :**

```
$tableContent = $this->cetak->Statistik_Content()['table_1'];

if (is_array($tableContent) || $tableContent instanceof Traversable) {
    foreach ($tableContent as $key => $value) {

        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($key, $value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize it till now :D

Comment: we all make some silly mistakes :D :D *Happy Coding*

Answer (score 0):

You should remove one foreach:

```
$tableContent = $this->cetak->Statistik_Content()['table_1'];

   if (is_array($tableContent) || $tableContent instanceof Traversable) {
            foreach ($tableContent as $key => $value) { // **This one generates an error**
                $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($key, $value);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I see it now, the problem is me. I tried to foreach the int var. Got this problem and didnt realize it. Thank you!